# Is it possible to use a check box or radio button in place of a submit button?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a form that allows me to dynamically add additional rows to a form using javascript but the button associated with adding new rows is too "bulky" and the script already incorporates the use of a check box that has to be checked in order to delete any rows associated with it, So I want to know if it's possible to use the check box to add and remove rows instead of a button?
Here is the jsFiddle of the script http://jsfiddle.net/2gPfn/9/ and the code:

```
 function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);             
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            newcell.children[0].name = newcell.children[0].name + rowCount;
            console.log(newcell.children[0].name);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

Basically what I want to do is to add a new row the user will check the box and a new row will be added with a new check box.
If they uncheck the previous checkbox the row will be deleted. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">`?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but it's a BAD idea. checkboxes are for choices, not actions.

Comment: @acdcjunior yes I tried that and it didn't work, that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: @MarcB Can you elaborate on why it's a BAD idea other then they are for choices not actions?

Comment: Don't change what the user is used to. Input ARE INPUT, buttons are buttons (besides input type="submit").

Comment: UI elements have their standard purposes. When you start changing how those UI elements behave to suit your wants/desires, you'll only confuse users. Every other app/webpage/etc.. in the universe uses checkboxes to make selections, and they come to your site, and hitting a checkbox makes the page grow... what then? how to they add another row? Uncheck the box? that'll just remove that row now...

Comment: @MarcB So basically you are saying people are stupid and can't figure out that checking the box adds a row? This isn't for the world to use this is for me to use so the only person that needs to know what it does is me. Honestly I didn't ask for an opinion on how I should use a check button that's totally irrelevant to the question. Sorry if that offends you but I can make my forms work to my needs without caring what anyone else thinks.

Comment: Sorry for assuming you're coding for a larger audience than yourself. Feel free to do whatever you want to do in your own little world. But if you take this out in the wild, then expect to get slammed for stupid design decisions. In the mean time, I'm going to explore renaming the  `del` command to `format`, and alias `ls` to `rm -rf /`. It's my own system, I'll NEVER get burned by that. </sarcasm>

Comment: maybe you should know more about what the process is being used for instead of knocking what people choose to do? There is no rule or law that states a check box HAS to be used as a check box only. Stay inside your box if you like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really understand why you'd want to do this.  But, if I'm understanding you correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/2gPfn/13/

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" onclick="doIt(this, 'dataTable')">
```

```
function doIt(el, tableID) {
    if (el.checked) {
        addRow(tableID);
    } else {
        deleteRow(el);
    }
}

function addRow(tableID) {
    /*  same as original */
}

function deleteRow(el) {
    var row = el.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you James that works perfectly, It's for my personal use for a form within my company that only myself and my employees will use. Basically it just makes the form not as bulky and easier to use on a tablet or Toughbook. It's not for the world to use, but thanks for keeping on topic with it you helped me a great deal!

Comment: James this works great but there is one problem, if you happen to double click on the check box it adds two rows and you can't delete one of them.